# Webpack Extract-Text-Plugin Output Multiple CSS Files (Both Minified and Not Minified)

Tags: javascript, webpack, extracttextwebpackplugin

I write style in SCSS, and I want to use webpack to build both minified and not minified css files.
So I set my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const extractSASS = new ExtractTextPlugin('assets/styles/[name].css');
const extractMiniSASS = new ExtractTextPlugin('assets/styles/[name].min.css');

module.exports = {
    entry: './Scripts/main.js',
    output: { path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/'), filename: 'scripts/bundle.js' },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractSASS.extract({
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractMiniSASS.extract({
                    use: [{ loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } }, 'sass-loader'],
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['es2015'] } }],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(), extractSASS, extractMiniSASS],
};
```

But after I run `npm run build`, I get some errors:

```
ERROR in ./SCSS/main.scss
Module build failed:
$primary_color: #99dd00;
^
      Invalid CSS after "e": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "exports = module.ex"
      in D:\Test\WebpackTest\CSSLoaderTest\SCSS\main.scss (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./Scripts/main.js 3:0-28
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js??ref--1-0!node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-1!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!SCSS/main.scss:
       [0] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js?{"id":2,"omit":0,"remove":true}!./node_modules/css-loader?{"minimize":true}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./SCSS/main.scss 159 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! cssloadertest@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cssloadertest@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\nodejs\node_cache\_logs\2018-01-24T03_09_52_242Z-debug.log
```

If my webpack.config.js is error? How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible at the moment with the configuration that you are using.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5433

Viable solution to you problem is to use multiple configurations by returning array instead of object then you can pass the same loaders with diffrent config in each literal

```
 module.exports = [{
    entry: './Scripts/main.js',
    output: { path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/'), filename: 'scripts/bundle.js' },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractMiniSASS.extract({
                    use: [{ loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } }, 'sass-loader'],
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['es2015'] } }],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(), extractMiniSASS],
},
{
entry: './Scripts/main.js',
output: { path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/'), filename: 'scripts/bundle.js' },
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: extractSASS.extract({
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            }),
        },
    ],
},
plugins: [extractSASS],
},

]
```

Of course you should remove any duplicates that exist...
As this can get messy very fast there is a tool called **webpack-merge** that can split your config into separate files, remove duplicate loaders etc..

https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge

Comment: I can output both minified and not minified css files. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I have modified the `webpack.config.js`. Try this once.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: "assets/styles/[name].css"
});

const extractMiniSASS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: "assets/styles/[name].min.css"
});

module.exports = {
  entry: './Scripts/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/'),
    filename: 'scripts/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015']
            }
          }
        ]
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractSass.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: "css-loader"
            }, {
              loader: "sass-loader"
            }
          ],
          fallback: "style-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  }
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    extractSASS,
    extractMiniSASS
  ]
};
```

Comment: I have installed style-loader, and change the rule to: { test: /\.scss$/, use: extractSASS.extract({ use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] })},            { test: /\.scss$/, use: extractMiniSASS.extract({ use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?importLoaders=1', 'sass-loader']})},
It still has the same error.

Comment: use the above configuration once and try. do not include the extractSASS in the rules.

Comment: It works find, but it didn't build out any css file.

Comment: I have modified the answer, try that once and let me know

Comment: I try to change my webpack.config.js with your codes, and it work fine, but it only builds a css file.